# React paypal hosted fields mount then unmount almost immediately

Tags: reactjs, paypal

Im using [react-paypal-js](https://github.com/paypal/react-paypal-js) to include paypal payments in my portfolio app. However the hosted fields component mounts then just unmounts almost immediately. I have no idea why this behaviour is. Here is some code.

**PaymentsModal.tsx**

```
  {isLoading ? (
    <FontAwesomeIcon
      icon={faSpinner}
      spin
      className="w-5 h-5 mx-auto my-5"
    />
  ) : errors.length > 0 ? (
    <p className="mx-auto my-5 text-sm">An error occurred </p>
  ) : clientTokenResponse ? (
    <PayPalScriptProvider
      options={{
        "client-id": process.env.REACT_APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID!,
        components: "buttons,hosted-fields",
        "data-client-token": clientTokenResponse.client_token,
        intent: "capture",
        vault: false,
      }}
    >
      {selectingPaymentMethod === "credit-card" ? (
        <CreditCardInput />
      ) : (
        <PayPalInput />
      )}
    </PayPalScriptProvider>
  ) : (
    <FontAwesomeIcon
      icon={faSpinner}
      spin
      className="w-5 h-5 mx-auto my-5"
    />
  )}
```

**CreditCardInput.tsx**

```
export const CreditCardInput = () => {
  return (
    <PayPalHostedFieldsProvider
      createOrder={() => {
        return Promise.resolve("Test");
      }}
    >
      <p>
        Card Number
        <span>*</span>
      </p>
      <PayPalHostedField
        id="card-number"
        className="card-field"
        hostedFieldType="number"
        options={{
          selector: "#card-number",
          placeholder: "4111 1111 1111 1111",
        }}
      />
      <p>
        CVV<span>*</span>
      </p>
      <PayPalHostedField
        id="cvv"
        className="card-field"
        hostedFieldType="cvv"
        options={{
          selector: "#cvv",
          placeholder: "123",
          maskInput: true,
        }}
      />
      <p>
        Expiration Date
        <span>*</span>
      </p>
      <PayPalHostedField
        id="expiration-date"
        className="card-field"
        hostedFieldType="expirationDate"
        options={{
          selector: "#expiration-date-field",
          placeholder: "MM/YYYY",
        }}
      />
      <SubmitPayment />
    </PayPalHostedFieldsProvider>
  );
};
```

I have tried really looking at the docs and i found this statement which i think might be a hint but i found it hard to interpret.

> Note: Take care when using multiple instances of the PayPal Hosted Fields on the same page. The component will fail to render when any of the selectors return more than one element.

Check out their [storybook](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/paypal-paypalhostedfields--default) to see if you can fish something out if necessary.I have created a short youtube video (8 seconds) showing this error. Watch it [here](https://youtu.be/W4x2j7cs2H0).

*Please help I have been stuck for days on this error*. I have verified that the clientTokenResponse is valid so it's safe to assume that it is working.

Comment: What's in the browser console?

Comment: @PrestonPHX nothing. The console is clean

Comment: Create a new sandbox app and deploy a minimal reproducible example to a code sandbox.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. But when I've changed client id to a different one, input fields doesn't get disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

**[Paypal Developer Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/#link-beforeyoubeginyourintegration) says,**

This integration requires a sandbox business account with the Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments capability. Your account should automatically have this capability.

To confirm that Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments are enabled for you, check your sandbox business account as follows:

1. Log into the [PayPal Developer Dashboard](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/), go to **Apps & Credentials**. In the REST API apps, select the name of your app.
2. Go to **Features > Accept payments**.
3. Select the **Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments** checkbox and select **Save Changes**.

If you don't see **Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments** under **Features > Accept payments** check this option is available for your country and currency from [developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/#link-eligibility](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/#link-eligibility)

You can see your **Sandbox Region** under **Sandbox account info** in **Apps & Credentials** section (same as step 1 above)