# How to get eligible to use HOSTED FIELDS in react-paypal-js

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Yesterday I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76355799/react-paypal-hosted-fields-mount-then-unmount-almost-immediately) about why my PayPalHostedFieldsProvider component kept unmounting. After scouring the internet and running stacks of debuggers I found this warning

> This  provider component wraps the form
> field elements and accepts props like createOrder().
>
> This provider component is designed to be used with the
>  component.
>
> Warning: If you don't see anything in the screen probably your client
> is ineligible. To handle this problem make sure to use the prop
> notEligibleError and pass a component with a custom message. Take a
> look to this link if that is the case:
> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/

on running `paypal.HOSTEDFIELDS.isEligible()` I was glad that it logged out false meaning I isolated the error. Question. How do I make myself eligible to use HOSTED FIELDS? The docs don't help much for some reason. For example here is some info I found on the docs.

> Before you can accept card payments on your website, set up your
> sandbox business account to accept card payments as follows:
> Log into the PayPal Developer Dashboard, go to My Apps & Credentials >
> Sandbox > REST API apps, and select the name of your app. Go to
> Sandbox App Settings > App feature options > Accept payments and
> select Advanced options. Select the Advanced Credit and Debit Card
> Payments checkbox and select Save. If you created a sandbox business
> account through sandbox.paypal.com, and the advanced credit and debit
> card payments status for the account is disabled, complete the sandbox
> onboarding steps.

After following all these steps I can't find the `Advanced Options` *check the below image* that they seem to reference on the docs and by proxy I can't get the checkbox to click so I'm kind of confused [image: (screenshot attached)]
Statement 4 isn't helping either because it's ambiguous beyond comprehension because of how this

> and the advanced credit and debit card payments status for the account is disabled

how do I know if it is disabled if I can't see it at all? Anyways **How do I become eligible to use HOSTEDFIELDS in my React app? Any help my way I will really appreciate it.**

Answer (score 0):

Country and currency requirements for hosted fields are documented [in the Advanced guide.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/#link-eligibility)

New [sandbox accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts) for those countries should already have the product enabled, but if not log in with the sandbox business account at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/bizsignup

Comment: So does this mean only certain countries and or currencies are allowed and what happens to a person whose country or currency is not listed? Should I just explicitly complete the verification by clicking on your last link?

Comment: Accounts from other countries cannot integrated Advanced/Hosted Fields.

Comment: F*ck this sh*t mahn